# sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory from exec command

Tags: php, linux, bash

I have a php server running some code in background using Gearman server.
The command line php script is running in the background. In the middle, there is one server (walker) which is always running and listening to some events. When I listen to some specific event it fires another command line command using php exec ("some command").

If this server is running fresh, then it works ok, but after some hours it starts giving:

```
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
```

where we use exec();

Any idea on how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

This error indicates that `getcwd()` returned `NULL` with `errno` set to `ENOENT`.

`getcwd()` will return `ENOENT` if the current working directory was unlinked. This seems to be the case here (according to the manpage, that's the only condition that causes `getcwd()` to return `ENOENT`).

Double check to make sure that no one deleted the directory while the server is running, or if the server code itself doesn't call `unlink()` on the current working directory. Someone, somewhere, is deleting it.

As a good practice, it is often recommended for daemonized processes to  `chdir()` to a known directory where the daemon will perform its duties. This is precisely to avoid this sort of problem (and also because a daemon running in a separate filesystem could prevent the administrator from unmounting that filesystem).

Comment: We have git implementation on server which deploy each time when someone commit or push the new code may git was removing all old file and adding new ?

Comment: @AmitRana Maybe. You can try and trace the process that runs with `strace()` or similar tools to see what syscalls it is invoking.